# How to get AWS Status Checks for an Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to retrieve, via AMAZON CLI tools, the 'Status Checks' information, which is displayed for an EC2 Instance in the console. For example 'Pending' or '2/2 checks passed'. I have used the following command:

```
  ec2-describe-instances [instance_id ...]
```

However, it only returns Instance State info such as 'Running', 'Stopping' etc. I want the more granular information as displayed in the Status Checks column in the AWS Console. Does anyone know the command to retrieve this information for an instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [describe-instance-status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html). This will return, among other things, both the System Status and Instance Status as displayed on the 'Status Check' tab in the EC2 web console.

Example Request as made for a running, healthy instance:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids i-abcd1234
```

Example Output as made for a running, healthy instance:

```
{
    "InstanceStatuses": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-abcd1234",
            "InstanceState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "SystemStatus": {
                "Status": "ok",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed",
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "InstanceStatus": {
                "Status": "ok",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed",
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to review historical status checks, you can do so via [CloudWatch (linked documentation)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html) by reviewing the following EC2 metrics:

- StatusCheckFailed_Instance
- StatusCheckFailed_System